# Facebook like button flyout appears then disappears on a page with no other content

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, flyout

I have added a facebook like button to my page, however when it is clicked the flyout appears, and then disappears.

At first I thought it was other elements on the page hiding it, but the problem persisted even on blank pages.

Tried both the iframe and html 5 codes that were generated by facebook and neither seems to work.

iframe - http://jsfiddle.net/aDK95/1/
Html 5 - http://jsfiddle.net/L9nZZ/1/

In both cases it seems to been hidden by the hidden_elem class:

```
    #facebook .hidden_elem {
display: none !important;
}
```

It seems very similar to [this bug](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/333196690088728?browse=search_5096e5c9eb3261e85539689) reported at FB that was reported in May. However there doesn't seem to be much movement on it.

Has anyone else come across this? Know of any work arounds?

Answer (score 0):

I came across this bug and it flummoxed me for quite a while. The steps I took to rectify it are as follows:

1. Ensure that you have put in the Javascript SDK initialization
2. Make sure that the #fbroot div is not inside a hidden div
3. In the Open Graph tags on the page, the og:url has to be set to a https protocol
   and not a http protocol

Run your page through the Facebook Debugger at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug to check for any errors. Another interesting point which helped me resolve this was that when you put in your "URL to Like" value in the Like configurator, the dynamic like button generated shows whether that url would work well or not.